# PHP Comment Form Validation to Protect Against Spam

Tags: php, forms, validation, comments, spam-prevention

I am building a comment form for a website. Eventually, it will be a popup jquery form utilizing ajax. I am trying to get the php together right now and want to make sure that I cover all of the bases to protect against spam.

There are four fields: email, name, url, and comment. This is what I have for the php so far:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
    print "E-mail is correct";

    $to      = 'asdfdsafasdfsda@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

} else {
    print "E-mail is not correct";
}
```

Just checking to make sure that the user is using a proper email address. I am not utilizing a database so am not worried as much about SQL injection or other database related problems. I just want the form to be secure against spam-bots.

What are the other elements I should include in my php to protect against spam?

Comment: add a captcha for better security

Comment: Personally, I'm trying to get around using a captcha. Are there other ways to protect my form?

Comment: While still relatively easy to bypass by bots, you could add a csrf token as a hidden field to your form, and validate it on the PHP side.  That is, add a hidden element with a random value (e.g. `86256885a7d15077a6483ec57879fe7109e1f254`), store it, and when the form is submitted, check to see if that value is a valid token.  It adds some complexity on your part since you will have to store and manage those codes.  Also most bots will pick up pretty easily on hidden values in the form so it arguably doesn't help a lot.

Comment: Thank you @drew010. I will try to add a crsf token. Any other measures I can take rather than adding a captcha?

Comment: Adding a honeypot trap to the php increases security, after further investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally not decide if a message is spam or a desired text, so syntactic checks like the one you did for the email won't work.

there are on the other hand some solutions out there that try to find certain properties that could identify a message as spam. you can for instance look into http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet

a common solution is to use a captcha. that is a picture containing some obfuscated text only a human can read. google provides a simple captcha system, if you want to try: http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: Yeh I am trying to get around using a captcha. Not using wordpress either but I guess I could look into akismet. Are there other methods?

Comment: if you have a community you could have them identify spam. youtube makes use of this approach. you can up/down-vote comments, mark them as spam or report them for various reasons.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is have a pop up js form that a user can submit a comment to the owner of the website. They input their name, email, and comment then press submit and php sends their comment to the owner of the website. Not a high volume website, but spam bots have taken control and send a bunch of email to the owner when all he wants is customer comments. Any ideas?

Comment: use captcha. spam is if not the most prominent problem on the internet. there is no easy solution to this problem or we wouldn't be having it.

Comment: someone suggested crsf token? thoughts?

Comment: i don't see how crsf is related to preventing spam. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Use an anti-spam database. [Botscout](http://www.botscout.com) has a really good one, as well as Spambusted. They have code samples and plugins for all major open-source scripts.

As for what information you need, one important information would be the user's IP.

The CSRF token is a good idea and it helps make sure that the commnets only originate from your website (thus not allowing someone to post a comment from a script outside of your website), but it's not particularly effective against a spammer who knows what he's doing.

Captcha is a good solution as well (and the Google Recaptcha is very easy to include), but it can be cumbersome for your end users.

If the only functionality you want to have is comments, than you might also want to try an already established solution, like [Disqus](http://disqus.com)

Answer (score 0):

***[Captcha Ads](http://www.adscaptcha.com/)*** 

I haven't used it but read about it. Concept is appealing. It is easier to read for user and you make money in the process.

PS: please do post what you ended up implementing besides recaptcha.

Comment: Hi as I pointed out earlier I am trying not to use captcha; from a design standpoint. I dont want to complicate the user experience. Any other ideas?

Comment: oh i mentioned just in case you are interested in making money. other idea is to implement Facebook comment. People usually do not vandalize or spam when they are logged in Facebook.